# How to use suggestquestion in QnA Maker?

Tags: azure-qna-maker

I started leaned QnA Maker. I have a question：

How to use suggestquestion in QnA Maker？ 
Can any one give me example ？

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about the capability to suggest several answers where the match confidence is similar. There are many samples on the [Botbuilder-Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs) Github repo (nodejs page linked), including one for a [Qna Maker Active Learning Bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/48.qnamaker-active-learning-bot), which should give you what you need. Specifically, the file in the Helpers folder shows how to make the call, filter the results, and if there is more than one "good" answer, build an array of suggestedQuestions and push those to the user.